# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value UPDATE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android

I am making an android application that connects to an external mysql database and i fetch the images from database successfully. when i click on the single item it will open another activity with selcted item data with update button.i successfuly retrive the data.but when i click update button it shows the bellow error

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value UPDATE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

```js
activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>



list_items.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

</RelativeLayout>



Single_item.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```css
Mainactivity.java code
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDailog;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>myarralist;
    JSONArray countrys=null;
    ListView listView;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    JSONfunctions jfunction=new JSONfunctions();


    private static String url_all_products="http://192.168.1.7/abc/get_all_products.php";
    static String TAG_SUCCESS="success";
     static  String TAG_PRODUCTS="image";
     static  String TAG_IMGID="ImageID";
     static  String TAG_NAME="ImageDesc";
     static  String TAG_DESC="Desc";
     static  String TAG_FLAG="ImagePath";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DOWNLoaddata().execute();


    }
    private class DOWNLoaddata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDailog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDailog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            pDailog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDailog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            myarralist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            List<NameValuePair>params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            jsonObject=jfunction.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
            Log.d("All countrys", jsonObject.toString());
            try {

                jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("image");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String>map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("ImageID", jsonObject.getString("ImageID"));
                    map.put("ImageDesc", jsonObject.getString("ImageDesc"));
                    map.put("Desc", jsonObject.getString("Desc"));
                    map.put("ImagePath", jsonObject.getString("ImagePath"));
                    myarralist.add(map);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                 Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            adapter=new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, myarralist);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            pDailog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}


Singleactivity.java code

public class Singleitemview extends Activity {

    String id;
    String country;
    String desc;
    String flag;
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    Bitmap bmimg=null;
    Button btnupdate;
    EditText edcou,eddesc;
    TextView txtid;
    ImageView imf;
    JSONfunctions jfun=new JSONfunctions();

    private static String url_update_product="http://192.168.1.7/abc/update_product.php";
    //private static String url_product_detials="http://192.168.1.5/android_connect/get_product_details.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS="success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS="image";
    private static final String TAG_COUNT="ImageDesc";
    private static final String TAG_DESC="DESC";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGEPATH = "ImagePath";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_item);

        new Loaddata().execute();
        Intent i=getIntent();
        id=i.getStringExtra("ImageID");
        country=i.getStringExtra("ImageDesc");
        desc=i.getStringExtra("Desc");
        flag=i.getStringExtra("ImagePath");

        edcou=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        eddesc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnupdate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new save().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    class save extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdialog=new ProgressDialog(Singleitemview.this);
            pdialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {



            country=edcou.getText().toString();
            desc=eddesc.getText().toString();
            //String img=imf.getImageMatrix().toString();


            List<NameValuePair>params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageID", id));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageDesc", country));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Desc", desc));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImagePath", flag));

            JSONObject json=jfun.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product, "POST", params);
            Log.d("single countrys", json.toString());
            try {
                int success=json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success==1) {

                    //country=json.getString("ImageDesc");
                    //des=json.getString("Desc");
                    //edcou.setText(country);
                    //eddesc.setText(des);

                    //Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(i);
                    //finish();

                    Intent i=getIntent();
                    setResult(100,i);
                    finish();
                }else {
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sorry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      System.out.println("Not updated!");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pdialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public class Loaddata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdialog=new ProgressDialog(Singleitemview.this);
            pdialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                Intent i=getIntent();
                id=i.getStringExtra("ImageID");
                country=i.getStringExtra("ImageDesc");
                desc=i.getStringExtra("Desc");
                flag=i.getStringExtra("ImagePath");

                URL url=new URL(flag);
                HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
                bmimg=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                 Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
            TextView idd=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            EditText countryy=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText desdc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            ImageView imgb=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            idd.setText(id);
            countryy.setText(country);
            desdc.setText(desc);
            imgb.setImageBitmap(bmimg);

            pdialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}


JSONFunctions

public class JSONfunctions {
    static InputStream is=null;
    static JSONObject jObj=null;
    static String json="";

    public JSONfunctions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url,String method,List<NameValuePair>params)
    {
        try {

            if (method=="POST") {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
                is=httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("{")) {

                }
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();
            json=sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " +e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj=new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " +e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;

    }
    public static JSONObject getjObj() {
        return jObj;
    }
    public static void setjObj(JSONObject jObj) {
        JSONfunctions.jObj = jObj;
    } 


}


LOG CAT

02-20 01:32:12.820: E/JSON Parser(804): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 1 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

```html
PHP Code


<?php

/*
 * Following code will update a product information
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
    $response = array();


// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['ImageID']) && isset($_POST['ImageDesc']) && isset($_POST['Desc']) && isset($_POST['ImagePath'])) {

    $ImageID = $_POST['ImageID'];
    $ImageDesc = $_POST['ImageDesc'];
    $Desc = $_POST['Desc'];
    $ImagePath = $_POST['ImagePath'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';


    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();


    // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE image SET ImageDesc = '$ImageDesc', Desc = '$Desc', ImagePath = '$ImagePath' WHERE ImageID = $ImageID");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully updated
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully updated.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

LOG CAT

02-20 01:32:12.820: E/JSON Parser(804): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 1 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Better you post your response what you getting.Then only it is easy to identify.I think the response is in wrong format

Comment: `echo "UPDATE image ` is a prime suspect..

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `echo "UPDATE image` line the output is something like:

```
UPDATE image...
{ some: { valid: 'json' }}
```

And that's not valid JSON. You have to remove the `echo "UPDATE` to make the output valid JSON.

Comment: Please post the output of your php script

Comment: when i run my php script i got this  {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}

Comment: so you can't have the message "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value UPDATE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" anymore. I think you have many issues in your code (I see some == with strings). My advise is to use one question per issue, Matryoshka doll questions are hard to follow.